# Opera truncates cookies on Joomla

Tags: php, cookies, joomla, opera

I'm developing an application in Joomla! 3.x which uses JWT cookies to grant some privileges. Everything works fine with Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but when it comes to Opera, my cookies are truncated.

How I set the cookies:

```
$inputCookie = JFactory::getApplication()->input->cookie;
$inputCookie->set("myCookie", $myCookie, 0);
```

Instead of a well-formed base64 encoding of a JWT, which I get on every other browser, Opera shows me only this:

```
o42io94enaeq3ellgfnafhdun3
```

Deleting the cookies does not work, since the cookie is always truncated when it gets stored.

Additional informations: Opera version is 46 on Mac. Using Opera 46 on Windows I have no problems with cookies.

Comment: Opera and IE use a `max bytes per domain` limit. Are you by any chance going over it? A quick googling shows "Opera allows 4096 bytes".

Comment: When the cookie is correctly set, the whole cookies for the domains total under 300 bytes

Answer (score 0):

It was the cache's fault. I still don't understand *exactly* what happened but it was simply solved by switching to private browsing.

The application uses redirects along with cookies and Opera probably cached some partial information (I still don't get how it managed to have only half a cookie, though). Switching to private browsing or otherwise deleting cookies and cache forced Opera to accept the whole cookie and everything worked. It seems to happen every few (about two or three) visit on the page.